# How can i delete the Single entry rows in SAS

Tags: sas

what i mean is as below:

```
id_numbers: 1234 1234 1234 5678 3428 9865 9865
Seq_id:      1    2    3    1    1    1    2
```

Now, what i want is to delete those id_numbers which appears only once.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use PROC SORT with the NOUNIQUEKEY option to remove unique entries.

```
Proc sort data=have nouniquekey out=want;
By id;
Run;
```

Comment: How did I not know about this!  When I want to investigate duplicates, I always have to use nodupkey with dupout= and then merge it back, keeping only obs that aren't in the dupout= dataset.  This is...significantly easier.

Comment: Its new as of SAS 9.3

Comment: Hi Reeza,Thank you for the Query. I had tried it, however it does not delete the 1's as Sas is taking Seq-Id 1 as not unique.

Comment: Please post better sample data and expexted output then.

Comment: Seq_id shouldn't be in the BY statement only ID.

Comment: Your first variable is labeled ID. Ps if you post useable data you get better code in the answers. I'm too lazy to type up your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `proc_sql`:

```
proc sql;
    delete from t
        where id_number in (select id_number from t group by id_number having count(*) = 1);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have used this query, however i am getting the  "ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row."....could you suggest why would i be getting it?...Thank you

Comment: Arrgh.  The `=` should have been `in`.